# cocoapods installation stuck on "Updating local specs repositories"

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Any help please I have been waiting so long for this and it didn't show me any improvement.Still stucking at `Updating local specs repositories`

Actually i was trying to update pod files of library that I use on my xcode.I close it yesterday because it takes too long.And today i run again,doing `control + c` and run `pod install` again.

It didn't work,stucking at `Updating local specs repositories`

When I open my Xcode,many errors occur because of pod issue..

Please I need help!

Comment: Is this an issue with a specific version of cocoapods? This is still an issue 19 months later.

Comment: @jungledev, yeah. I didn't experience like since 1.2. I don't know if others still happening or not. But, that is the answer anyway.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There's an known error with http://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/

You can try to fix it by doing:

```
pod repo remove master
pod setup
pod install
```

Comment: very weird but this fixed my problem... thanks for posting.

Comment: FWIW, `$ pod setup` took ~9 minutes for me. I think I just didn't wait long enough for `$ pod update` to complete updating its repo. It would be helpful if `$ pod update` showed progress in downloading 1M+ git objects.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! I had a similar issue, trying to run pod update but getting the following error message: "fatal : ambiguous 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree"

Comment: I cancelled `pod update` after 15 minutes and >1gb download.  This resolved the issue for me.  On a slowish connection (14mbps down, 3.7up) it took me 8 minutes 15 seconds for this whole process to complete.

Comment: not work for me it's stuck at 
Removing spec repo `master`

Comment: @FadiAbuzant It is takes some time to remove. Also the `master` is actually called `cocoapods` now: `pod repo remove cocoapods`.  And yet not work for me.

Answer (score 16):

For me it already happened a few times, always after cocoapods failing to contact github on a previous run if I'm not mistaken.

I solved by simply deleting the contents of `~/.cocoapods/repos.` and running the pods again

Comment: Thank you, this helped.

I did continue to have a similar issue as described in the original post and was able to really speed things up by cloning `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` directly into this repos directory.  After cloning I ran `pod update` and the method executed in a timely manner.

`rm -rfv ~/.cocoapods/repos*
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
cd /myProject
pod update`

Comment: the  @Destry solution was the only that worked for me. Many thanks.

Comment: @AndresCanella the same for me.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like specs repos will be updated by default when you run pod update. Including --no-repo-update in the pod update command solved the issue for me

```
pod update POD_NAME --no-repo-update
```

Reference:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4218#issuecomment-141678644

Answer (score 0):

Also on these days some users sugest update Ruby via homebrew

Check this issue:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7447